# How to fix PanicException when converting int to pl.Date

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to convert a 4 million `pl.Series` from `i64` to `pl.Date`. My code does not work because of `PanicException` which nature I am not really familiar with:

```
sample = pl.DataFrame({
    'install_time': [1595404176, 
                     1595404176,
                     1595404177,
                     1595404180,
                     1595404184,
                     1595404185,
                     1595404191,
                     1595404192,
                     1595404195]
})

sample.with_columns(pl.col('install_time').cast(pl.Date))
```

As the result of the execution of the piece of code above I receive the following error: `PanicException: out-of-range date`. I really do not have idea on how to fix so I will be grateful for any advice and suggestions.

Comment: Try converting to some datetime and then only cutting it to be date only. Because int->datetime will for sure try to pass timestamp, while int->date might use something else - and causing this error (e.g. python's built-in date has fromordinal that is number of days since "0" - Jan 1 of year 1 is 1 - and year 4368069 is out of range for built-in date as well :P)

Comment: @h4z3 hey! thank you, I will try to do this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested in comments by @h4z3, I converted UNIX to datetime and then to date. It worked fine for me:

```
sample.with_columns(pl.from_epoch('install_time', time_unit='s').cast(pl.Date).alias('dt_install'))
```